# conditional global format to UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, styles

I'm developing an app and for applying a global format, for doing that I added next lines below to my appDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    [self customizeAppearance];

    return YES;
}

-(void)customizeAppearance{

    int iOSVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] intValue];

    if (iOSVersion >= 7) {

        //Customizing UIButton
        [[UIButton appearance]setBackgroundColor:(UIColorFromRGB(toolbarTintColor))];
        [[UIButton appearance]setTitleColor:(UIColorFromRGB(toolbarTextColor)) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      }

    if (iOSVersion < 7) {

        //Customizing UIButton
        [[UIButton appearance]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

I did these two styles depending of iOS version which changes UIbutton style, but I want it to be applied just to UIButtons, not UIBarButtonItems is that possible??

taking this one step further I want to apply globally this format just to UIButtons inside UIView elements (not in UITableViewCells or so) can that be done???

thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing this should be working in the manner you've described. UIBarButtonItem doesn't inherit from UIButton as the name would suggest. That means that when you use the UIAppearance protocol on UIButton, the changes you've made wont effect any instance of UIBarButtonItem.

> NSObject >> UIBarItem >>UIBarButtonItem
>
> NSObject >> UIResponder >>UIView >> UIControl >> UIButton

And to answer your second question, you're probably better off just making a subclass of UIButton to customize if you only wish for the customization to be applied on certain instances of the button. By doing this, you can add logic to the subclass to change its appearance depending on the class of its superview. This could be done with the use of something like this:

```
[self.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]];
```

Or, if you do still want to use UIAppearance, see @null's answer for an example.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!! look when I try with [self.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] it says: "Property 'superview' not found on object AppDelegate"

Comment: @juandejesusss It wouldn't work. That is code that you would use within a subclass of UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below proxy:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyView class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

For more information check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

By the way setting appearance for `UIButton` doesn't change the appearance for `UIBarButtonItems`.

Comment: works great with a single class but what if I need this format for two or more like this: [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[classVC1 class], [classVC2 class], nil]setTitleColor:(UIColorFromRGB(toolbarTextColor)) forState:UIControlStateNormal]; this is not working or is it required to add a line of code for each class??

Comment: This array of views represent the containment hierarchy, it is not the list of containers, by doing this you are saying button contained in classVC1 which it is contained in classVC2. You need to split this array. 'add line of code for each class'.